# Qooxdoo table add/remove columns dynamically

Tags: qooxdoo

Is there a way without re creating the table every time to add/remove columns in the table widget on demand?

From my research I can't find a way to accomplish this with the table widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry, that can't be done, as explained in the following note in the documentation for the `setColumns` method in `qx.ui.table.model.Abstract`:

`Note: You can not change the number of columns this way.  The number
      of columns is highly intertwined in the entire table operation,
      and dynamically changing it would require as much work as just
      recreating your table.  If you must change the number of columns
      in a table then you should remove the table and add a new one.`

You can, however, show and hide columns using the column visibility features, i.e., the `setColumnVisibile` method of the column model.

Derrell